Razorpay subscription activation delay after payment: How to Handle It?
I have implemented Razorpay gateway for distribute subscription to my user.
After user makes payment, Razorpay receive it quickly after that Razorpay have to start subscription for that. but meanwhile, it takes the delay

Here is the webhook event I received after user makes a payment:

payment.authorized

payment.captured

order.paid
it takes 30 to 40 second DELAY here!!

subscription.activated

subscription.charged

subscription.authenticated (I distribute paid plan access here)



I got subscription info only in subscription events so I can't distribute paid plan access in payment or order.paid event.
Razorpay have to not take this much delay start the subscription
How to solve this issue?

Perhaps you should take it up with Razorpay?

I'm considering this is a global issue. How developer who integrated subscription payments with Razorpay handle this.?
